# "Ignavia": di che cosa è accusato il parroco?

Tags: word-meaning

Questo brano è stato tratto dalle notizie di Euronews (il corsivo è mio):

> Giancarlo Manieri, il parroco della chiesa don Bosco, accusato di *ignavia* per non aver impedito lo svolgersi della cerimonia però, non ci sta a passare per l’unico colpevole e respinge le accuse al mittente: “Cinquecento persone che stavano lì – dei Casamonica – Lei li avrebbe fermati? Se questo era il boss, se questo ha fatto questo e quest’altro e quest’altro come mi avete detto, si può sapere perché era a piede libero?”

Ho cercato il significato di "ignavia", vocabolo a me sconosciuto, in alcuni dizionari. Comunque, non riesco a capire cosa significhi esattamente in questo contesto. Di che cosa si accusa a questo prete secondo Euronews?

Comment: Più largamente ignavia si riferisce alla colpa del non prendere una posizione attiva in generale e quindi per estensione alla semplice pigrizia / codardia, celeberrimo il riferimento di Dante a Celestino V, che rinunciò alla carica papale: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Che_fece_per_viltade_il_gran_rifiuto

Answer (score 11, accepted):

L'ignavia è la colpa (o il peccato, teologicamente) di chi, pur non compiendo attivamente un atto criminoso o comunque molto discutibile, tollera che lo si compia, non si oppone, lascia fare, arrivando eventualmente a collaborare.

Per qualunque italiano il riferimento implicito è agli ignavi come vengono descritti da Dante, fuori dall'Inferno vero e proprio, nel III canto della prima cantica, quali «coloro / che visser sanza ’nfamia e sanza lodo». Sono uniti agli «angeli che non furon ribelli / né fur fedeli a Dio, ma per sé fuoro» quando Lucifero si ribellò a Dio. La pena per gli ignavi è di correre eternamente dietro a una bandiera (per contrappasso, perché in vita non si schierarono mai), senza essere ammessi neppure nell'Inferno.